# Zend: How do i get values from a Select element form?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, select, element

Hi im new with zend and this question probably be ridiculous but i have a trouble getting values from the following:

```
            $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('_country');
            $country->setLabel('Country:');
            $country->addMultiOptions(array('0'=>'United States',
                                            '1'=>'Bolivia',
                                            '2'=>'Argentina',
                                            '3'=>'Afganistan'));
            $country->setRequired(true);
```

But im not sure how i can get the values, i tried like this on my controller:

```
if ($this->_request->getPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        $form = new App_Form_CustomerForm();

        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $customer = $customerDao->getById($id);             
                            $customer->setCountry($formData[0]['_country']);                
            $customerDao->save($customer);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');

            return;
```

Im thinking of use only html code to do this select but i want to know how get these values .

Answer (score 0):

you can get the values from zend element using the `getValue()` method
 [Populating and Retrieving Values](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators.errors)
The code would be

```
if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
    $customer = $customerDao->getById($id);             
    $customer->setCountry($form->getValue('_country'));                
    $customerDao->save($customer);
    $this->_helper->redirector('index');

    return;
    }
```